# How to retrieve the last tag's content of xml file using sax parser in android?

Tags: android

Here is the xml file data which I want to parse. I want to get the last tag i.e content of `<RECEIPTNO>`. Can anyone help?

```
<MSPDB><COMPANYNO>01</COMPANYNO><SALESPERSON>01101</SALESPERSON><MAPNO>5</MAPNO><CUSTOMERNO>1</CUSTOMERNO><ORDERNO>1</ORDERNO><QUOTENO>1</QUOTENO><LASTINVOICENO>1</LASTINVOICENO><RECEIPTNO>8</RECEIPTNO></MSPDB>
```

Here is the code I have tried using SAX parser.

```
String FILE_NAME = "Mspdb.xml";
        File file=new File(Supporter.getAppCommonPath(),FILE_NAME);
        FileInputStream stream;
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream(file);
            String[] result=parseDocument(stream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

public String[] parseDocument(InputStream stream)
{
    String[] resultArray=new String[8];
    String result="";
    SAXParserFactory parserFactory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        SAXParser parser=parserFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader=parser.getXMLReader();
        Xmlhandler handler=new Xmlhandler();
        reader.setContentHandler(handler);
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource();
        inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        inputSource.setByteStream(stream);
        reader.parse(inputSource);


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    result=resultArray[7];
    return resultArray;
}

  class Xmlhandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    private String tempVal;
    private String receiptNo;
    private String value;

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.startDocument();
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.endDocument();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        value="";
        tempVal="";

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Value:" + tempVal);
        System.out.println("End:" + localName);

        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("RECEIPTNO"))
        {
            receiptNo=tempVal;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        value=new String(ch, start, length);
        tempVal=value+tempVal;
    }



}
```

Comment: If you only want the value of the RECEIPTNO tag and you are sure that there is only one of it then using a sax parser is overkill. Just use .indexOf("<RECEIPTNO>") and .indexOf("</RECEIPTNO>") and then .substring().

Comment: @greenapps: Can u elaborate on how and where to use .indexOf() and .substring()?

Comment: Just apply them to the String which you call `the xml file data`.

Comment: Can you give the exact code pls?